# ios Strange UIKeyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikeyboard

I created a `UITextField`

[image]

UI is-->
[image]

But the background colour of the keyboard is white.

And when I click `UITextfield` a second time

[image]

The current page is covered by a white page

But When I check the Debug view Hierarchy
[image]

I did not find this white page.
And  I create a new project, there is no such problem.
So I guess: it must be my project's problem.

Can someone explain why ? It will be very kind.

Comment: what happened when you press return key on keyboard to hide keyboard?

Comment: are you adjusting the frame of the view if keyboard is present?

Comment: it's normally for hide keyboard.

Comment: i check my code, not found any category about UIKeyBoard & UIControl.i didn't do anything about for the keyboard present and hidden.

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of your code, but paste the code as text instead.